# Substitute for "upgradation"

Tags: word-usage

I came across a sentence that contains the word *upgradation*.

> The establishment of Van Dhan Vikas Kendra is for providing skill **upgradation** and capacity building training and setting up of primary processing and value addition facility.

This was underlined by my grammar checker as wrong. How can I improve this sentence?

Comment: Why isn't the ing-form acceptable, if [capacity] building, training, and setting [up of ...] all pass muster? (And note the listing commas.) (To be fair, I'd concede that 'the upgrading of skills' comes across better than 'skill upgrading.)

Comment: Thank you for this post. Apart from the horrendous phrase that is the subject of your question, it provides two examples of truly awful agglomerations of adjectival nouns In “capacity building training” and “value addition facility”. Lord Gnome would be proud of you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I offer, "Van Dhan Vikas Kendra was established to teach: skill building, capacity expansion, set up of primary processing and value addition facilitation."